# how to open pdf file in project folder using vaadin code?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have a PDF in project location how to open pdf file

my project name is MyProject

My pdf is under project folder

MyProject\Pdf\test.pdf how to open my pdf file

I need to open pdf file in the project location

I have tried below code

```
    final Button viewBtn= new Button("View Policy Schedule");       
 viewBtn.addClickListener( newButton.ClickListener()                                        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)  {
        Window window = new Window();   
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setCaption("Claim Form Covering Letter PDF");
        window.setWidth("800");
        window.setHeight("600");
        window.setModal(true);
        window.center();
        final String filepath = "Pdf//test.pdf";

         File f = new File(filepath);

         System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        Path p = Paths.get(filepath);
        String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();


        StreamResource.StreamSource s = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9138325634649289303L;

            public InputStream getStream() {
                try {

                    File f = new File(".");
                    System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    return fis;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };

        StreamResource r = new StreamResource(s, fileName);
        Embedded e = new Embedded();
        e.setSizeFull();
        e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
        r.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
        e.setSource(r);
        window.setContent(e);
        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
 }
});
```

It's not working I have got a file not found exception

Answer (score 0):

Move the PDF so you can read it from the classpath. If you are using Maven put it in src/main/resources. Otherwise put it in some package.

You can then read it using getResourcesAsStream() method of java.lang.class.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/test.pdf"); //classpath root
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/my/package/name/test.pdf"); //from some package
```

Updated

```
 final Button viewBtn= new Button("View Policy Schedule");       
     viewBtn.addClickListener( newButton.ClickListener()
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)  {
            Window window = new Window();   
            window.setResizable(true);
            window.setCaption("Claim Form Covering Letter PDF");
            window.setWidth("800");
            window.setHeight("600");
            window.setModal(true);
            window.center();

            StreamResource.StreamSource s = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

                public InputStream getStream() {
                    try {
                        return this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/test.pdf");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };

            StreamResource r = new StreamResource(s, fileName);
            Embedded e = new Embedded();
            e.setSizeFull();
            e.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
            r.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
            e.setSource(r);
            window.setContent(e);
            UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
     }
    });
```